# Telethon | Trying to add myself to a group

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Hello i'm trying to add my self to a group in telegram using telethon.

i tried this:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
updates = client(ImportChatInviteRequest('grouphash'))
```

but getting error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "jg.py", line 12, in 
>       updates = client(ImportChatInviteRequest('grouphash'))
>
> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.InviteHashInvalidError: The invite hash is invalid (caused by ImportChatInviteRequest)

Comment: Please note that the hash is the part after the link (e.g., in `https://t.me/<hash>`, **only the `<hash>` part** should be used). Further, usernames are not the "hash" either and those have `JoinChannelRequest`.

Comment: Thank you for helping. i used the hash part after the https://t.me/<hash> in my code where 'grouphash' is but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, `https://t.me/joinchat/<hash>` and `https://t.me/<username>` are what I meant (note they're different).

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove + in the hash example

link gruop https://t.me/+_7JK8SMJijw0ZjQx

so yo have to introduce only _7JK8SMJijw0ZjQx

```
client(ImportChatInviteRequest('_7JK8SMJijw0ZjQx'))
```